# String is a prefix of a valid IPv6

Tags: regex, ipv6

I'm working on auto-completion task and I want to check whether a given string is a prefix of a valid IPv6 address.
For example, the string "2001:" is a prefix of this ipv6 address "2001:db8::2:1" or can be a prefix of this ipv6 address "2001:a8::4:c".
My function should return true if a string is a prefix of some valid IPv6.
I've searched the internet and all I found was IPv6 validation only.
Thanks

Comment: are you looking for a regex to match a string that starts with  2000:   ?

Comment: Valid, global IPv6 addresses start with a `2` or `3`, and have four hexadecimal digits in the first word. It gets more complicated if you want to consider things like ULA.

Comment: @sniperd 2000: was just an example.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm looking for something that can tell me whether a given string is a prefix of any possible ipv6 address 
for example if the input string is X, then I want to know if there exist a string Y such that X+Y = valid ipv6 address

Comment: What do you mean by "valid IPv6 address?" From one perspective, any 128-bit integer is a valid IPv6 address. Do you mean can it be a source address, a destination address, it it forwardable, is it global, is it a multicast address, etc.? You must first define what you mean by a valid address.

Comment: For example, link-local IPv6 addresses (any address in the `fe80::/10` range) are valid IPv6 addresses, but those addresses cannot be routed. Does that disqualify them from your "valid IPv6 addresses?" You need to give us some context.

Comment: Yes Ron, any 128-bit integer was what I meant, without analyzing it's content but just the template, for example if a string is 2000:::af
then this wont be a valid start of an ipv6 address

Answer (score 1):

Basically the first 64 bit of an IPV6 address is considered as network prefix. You can use below regular expression to validate your network prefix.

```
var valueToTest=document.getElementById('networkprefix').value;

if ( /^((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}))*:((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}))*:((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}))*:((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}))$/g.test(valueToTest)) 
{
    alert("Valid Network Prefix");

}
else
{
    alert("InValid Network Prefix");
}
```

Comment: "_Basically the first 64 bit of an IPV6 address is considered as network prefix._" That is not entirely accurate. A standard IPv6 network is `/64`. The RIRs and ISPs will assign prefixes shorter than `/64`. For example, each site should be assigned a `/48` prefix that can be divided into `65,536` standard `/64` networks (we have a `/32` prefix). The ISPs will not advertise any prefix longer than `/48`. Some residential ISPs will assign `/56` or `/60` prefixes. You can, and should, use `/127` prefixes for point-to-point links, and `/128` prefixes for things like router loopbacks.